# What Risks come across if we run local web server in Mobile phone?

Tags: android, web-applications, webserver, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-website

What are the security issues we may come across, if we run local web server in the mobile phone to host web app.

Comment: Stackoverflow is used to help with specific errors or problems. Please specify more.

Comment: I want understand, if local web server is running in mobile will pose a security threat to web app like losing data etc